# How to upgrade Windows MySQL Server 5.7.26 to 8.0.16?

Tags: windows, mysql, upgrade, zip, mysql5

I am having trouble upgrading from MySQL Server 5.7.26 to MySQL Server 8.0.16.

Maybe it's just because I'm not a seasoned DBA, but to me the MySQL reference manual is quite vague.

From [MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual
:: 2.11.10 Upgrading MySQL on Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-upgrading.html#windows-upgrading-zip-distribution):

> 

**Upgrading MySQL Using the Windows ZIP Distribution:**

To perform an upgrade using the Windows ZIP archive distribution:

1. Download the latest Windows ZIP Archive distribution of MySQL from
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/.
2. If the server is running, stop it. If the server is installed as a
   service, stop the service with the following command from the
   command prompt:

   ```
   C:> SC STOP mysqld_service_name
   ```

   Alternatively, use **`NET STOP mysqld_service_name`**.

   If you are not running the MySQL server as a service, use **`mysqladmin`**
   to stop it. For example, before upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0, use
   **`mysqladmin`** from MySQL 5.7 as follows:

   ```
   C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqladmin" -u root shutdown
   ```

   > **Note**
   >   If the MySQL `root` user account has a password,
   >   invoke **`mysqladmin`** with the `-p` option and enter the password when
   >   prompted.
3. Extract the ZIP archive. You may either overwrite your existing
   MySQL installation (usually located at `C:\MySQL`), or install it into
   a different directory, such as `C:\mysql8`. Overwriting the existing
   installation is recommended.
4. Restart the server. For example,
   use the **`SC START mysqld_service_name`**
   or **`NET START mysqld_service_name`** command if you
   run MySQL as a service, or invoke **`mysqld`** directly otherwise.

Does this mean I literally just stop the service, drop the files inside the ZIP into the previous installation directory (which in my case is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\`), and then restart the service?

When I try this, the `SC START mysqld_service_name` command yields

```
SERVICE_NAME: MySQL57
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x1f40
        PID                : 12016
        FLAGS              :
```

and in Task Manager the process is reported as Stopped. 
I'm also unable to start or connect to the server from Workbench.

Can anyone help me with this?

I feel like I'm missing some critical step which is so obvious to DBAs that they deem it not even worth mentioning.

Comment: ZIP pack for update must be used by experienced admin only. I'd recommend you: 1) make full backup for all databases, including all objects 2) remove old server using uninstall 3) install new server using MSI installer 4) restore databases. This is long, but reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious as to why you use a ZIP file. I always use the [MySql installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) an would suggest that you try that.